# Software is not working when MS SQL server version is changed

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2005 database - server in my software (OS-XP). When I changed the server to SQL Server 2008 (OS-windows 7), the software didn't work.

I debugged the program and found `Array index out of bounds exception` in a part of a code, when I changed that code its working fine, can anyone please tell me what is the reason for the problem?

```
String cnnStr = String.Format("Data Source = {0}; Initial Catalog = {1}; Integrated Security = SSPI; persist security info=False; Trusted_Connection=Yes",ServerName, Databasae);

sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(cnnStr);
sqlConnection.Open();
```

**Original code**

```
 Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(sqlConnection));
 Database db = server.Databases[Databasae];
 Table Table = new Table(db, TableName);
 Column TimeColumn = new Column(Table, "DateTime");
 TimeColumn.DataType = DataType.DateTime;
 TimeColumn.Nullable = false;
 Column ValueColumn = new Column(Table, "Value");
 ValueColumn.DataType = DataType.Float;
 ValueColumn.Nullable = false;
 Table.Columns.Add(TimeColumn);
 Table.Columns.Add(ValueColumn);
 Table.Create();
```

**New code**

```
 StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
 query.Append("CREATE TABLE ");
 query.Append(TableName);
 query.Append(" (  [DateTime] DateTime , Value float(10) )");

 SqlCommand sqlQuery = new SqlCommand(query.ToString(), sqlConnection);
 SqlDataReader reader = sqlQuery.ExecuteReader();

 reader.Close();
```

Comment: Which part of your code threw array index out of bounds exception? Is the connection string format same for old as well as new code?

Comment: What's this line meant to be: `server.Databases[Databasae];`? What is `Databasae`?

Comment: Database db = server.Databases[Databasae]; exception appears when executing this line .

Comment: It is hard to answer your question. Please, post exception details for the original code here (stack trace). Also, these code samples are not equivalent, because first uses SMO, and the second uses pure ADO .NET. Also, SMO assemblies are SQL Server version-dependent. What version of SMO are you using to connect to SQL 2008? If it is version 9 (for SQL 2005), the you have to update SMO first and rebuild your application, using new version of SMO assemblies.

Comment: Databasae is the name of the database , sorry for the spelling mistakes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your SMO SDK to the SQL 2008 version and remove all of the 2005 references as you are no longer using SQL 2005.

You can read a bit more on the subject here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162129.aspx